# Debug Mode: See what is in SqlCommand

Tags: asp.net, sql, vb.net

I'd like to see what is about to be sent to the SQL Server from my SqlCommand before SQLCmd.ExecuteNonQuery() runs.

I'm trying to debug because I am receiving the following error:     ***System.FormatException: Failed to convert parameter value from a String to a Int32.***

Normally, I would use SQL Server Profiler to view what is being sent to SQL Server, but my statement is not making it that far.

Is there a way to determine what it is trying to convert? I am having problems determining which parameter is causing the error.

Comment: Can you view the Parameters collection of the SqlCommand object in the Quick Watch window?

Comment: As Greg said, the Quick Watch window ought to do it or use the Immediate window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the immediate window:

```
? SQLCmd.Parameters["@MyParam"].Value
```

Answer (score 3):

There's nothing that can quickly visualize it for you, but you can browse through the object and get at the internal list of parameters and view their names and values individually.

It will likely be faster just to write something that you can pass the command into and it will print out the name, `DbType`, `Value.ToString()` and `Value.GetType().Name` for each parameter.

```
void PrintCommand(DbCommand command)
{
    Console.WriteLine("CommandType: {0}", command.CommandType);
    Console.WriteLine("CommandText: {0}", command.CommandText);

    foreach(var parameter in command.Parameters)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("    Parameter {0}, {1}: \"{2}\" ({3})", 
            parameter.ParameterName, 
            parameter.DbType,
            parameter.Value,
            parameter.Value.GetType().Name);
    }
}
```