# Fix the update problem in ASP.NET and SQL Server

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, webforms

I am trying to update the data entered in the textboxes in ASP.NET in the database, but I am getting an @id error, can you help?

```
        Baglanti baglantimiz = new Baglanti();

        SqlConnection netbaglanti = baglantimiz.Baglan();

        SqlCommand komut = new SqlCommand("update genelayarlar set title = @title, isimsoyisim = @isimsoyisim, aciklama = @aciklama, instagram = @instagram, twitter = @twitter, facebook = @facebook, eposta = @eposta where id = @id", netbaglanti);
        komut.Connection = netbaglanti;

        komut.Parameters.AddWithValue("@title", TextBox1.Text);
        komut.Parameters.AddWithValue("@isimsoyisim", TextBox2.Text);
        komut.Parameters.AddWithValue("@aciklama", TextBox3.Text);
        komut.Parameters.AddWithValue("@instagram", TextBox4.Text);
        komut.Parameters.AddWithValue("@twitter", TextBox5.Text);
        komut.Parameters.AddWithValue("@facebook", TextBox6.Text);
        komut.Parameters.AddWithValue("@eposta", TextBox7.Text);
        komut.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", Label1.Text);

        komut.ExecuteNonQuery();

        netbaglanti.Close();

        Response.Redirect("anasayfa.aspx");
```

Comment: What is the error message? I suspect that using AddWithValue produces invalid parameters types. For example, you pass a label.Text (a string) for the ID parameter but the database expects an integer. Do not use AddWithValue. Instead use _Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.Int32).Value = Convert.ToInt32(Label1.Text)_

Comment: error message: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'Label' to data type int.'

Comment: So which control on the page is meant to hold the `@id` value? It seems like you're currently referencing a label on the page along the lines of `<asp:Label id="Label1" Text="Label" runat="server" />`

Comment: Don't use [addwithvalue](http://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/)

Comment: [edit] the error msg into your question.

Answer (score 1):

ID should be an integer

```
    komut.Parameters.Add("@id", SqlDbType.Int);
    komut.Parameters.AddWithValue("@title", TextBox1.Text);
    komut.Parameters.AddWithValue("@isimsoyisim", TextBox2.Text);
    komut.Parameters.AddWithValue("@aciklama", TextBox3.Text);
    komut.Parameters.AddWithValue("@instagram", TextBox4.Text);
    komut.Parameters.AddWithValue("@twitter", TextBox5.Text);
    komut.Parameters.AddWithValue("@facebook", TextBox6.Text);
    komut.Parameters.AddWithValue("@eposta", TextBox7.Text);
    komut.Parameters["@id"].Value =  Convert.ToInt32(Label1.Text);
```

Comment: 'The parameterized query '(@id int,@title nvarchar(3),@isimsoyisim nvarchar(9),@aciklama n' expects the parameter '@id', which was not supplied.'

Comment: Typically that means you are attempting to pass a C# null value. You need to debug your code, step through with debugger and check all the values are correct.

Comment: I solved the problem, but this time it returns empty, I don't get any error, but it doesn't update in the database

Comment: You can debug parameters as described in here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4832997/debug-mode-see-what-is-in-sqlcommand or use SqlProfiler https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27267017/how-to-use-sql-server-profiler-in-sql-server-with-your-asp-net-application